# Woocommerce edit address doesn't work - Any specific shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, frontend, shortcode

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J91RZ.png)

Hey! and thanks on advance!

when I do click on manage address in my frontend woocommerce dashboard I don't get to change my address. 
right now i have an URL say /edit-address and on that page i have the shortcode [woocommerce_my_account].

can you guys help me understand whats wrong.

Comment: what you see when you visit that page

Comment: There is nothing, i just see my normal account front end woocommerce dashboard.

Comment: please share your screenshot, if you are not allowed, upload your image to http://postimg.org/ and write the last keyword of the image link in comments